# CoreImage Memory problems in ios5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

Does anyone knows how to release memory while using core image framework to apply HUE changes on image?
Here is my code:-

```
        CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:currentImage];
        CIFilter * controlsFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIHueAdjust"];
        [controlsFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
        [controlsFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:slider.value] forKey:@"inputAngle"];
         CIImage *displayImage = controlsFilter.outputImage;
        UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:displayImage];

        CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
        if (displayImage == nil || finalImage == nil) {
            // We did not get output image. Let's display the original image itself.
            photoEditView.image = currentImage;
        }else {
            // We got output image. Display it.
            photoEditView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:displayImage fromRect:displayImage.extent]];
        }
        context = nil;
        [inputImage release];
```

Comment: What memory problems are you having?

Comment: my code is allocating around 25MB while editing and when editing is completed its releasing that memory.

Comment: why negative vote to this question ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to release this one as well :

```
[context createCGImage:displayImage fromRect:displayImage.extent]
```

by using the CGImageRelease(CGImageRef) method.

Comment: You should Accept the answer if it's the right one, it will help the other users viewing this question.